# Can't change keyboard shortcut in Source Insight

Tags: ide, source-insight

I'm working with Source Insight, and I want ctrl+A to select everything on the page. Reasonable enough, I think. So I make sure the command exists where I think it does -
[image: The edit menu featuring Select All]

yep, there it is. So I go to the key shortcuts, but I can't find the Select All function there.

[image: The Key Assignment screen, showing that the only function available starting with "Edit: Se" is Cut Selection or Paste]

[image: The Key Assignment screen with Edit: Select All typed and everything grayed out]

What am I missing, here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is in **Navigation: Select All**

[image: source insight select all]